# Send multiple GET API requests using HttpURLConnection in java

Tags: java, api

I am using below code to send GET api request. The url below has a parameter e.g. String url = "https://my/api"+variable+"test". I am using for loop to iterate through the list of variables (which are more than 2000) and create url to send get API request using below code. I want to send multiple api requests in parallel to reduce the overall time. Please suggest what is the best way for that.

```
    URL _url = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) _url.openConnection();

    Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return (new PasswordAuthentication(user,
                    password.toCharArray()));
        }
    };


    Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
   JSONObject Obj = new JSONObject(response.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you check out the Java ExecutorService:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

You can create async tasks and execute them on a thread pool, then wait for the results to complete. There are several good tutorials for this.

For instance:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial